# php add to time

Tags: php, time

Why doesn't $now2 work?

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); 
$now2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( "$now + 0.5 secs"));
```

Or how can I get it to work?

Comment: Since UNIX timestamps have a resolution of 1 second, that couldn't work either way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason its now working is because `PHP` does not recognize `0.5 secs` has valid

`0.5 secs` is not a valid date format .. but it is a valid `microtime`

Try

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
var_dump(strtotime( "$now + 1 secs"));
```

Output

```
int 1334188908
```

Answer (score 2):

time() returns the number of **seconds** since the epoch. It doesn't know anything about fractions of a second. You'll need to use microtime() if you need this level of accuracy (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Edit: You of course can't use microtime in the date() formatting, so you need to do a calculation prior and then use it. Similar to:

```
$now = microtime(true);
$newtime = $now + 0.5;

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", round($newtime,0) );
```

Depending on your requirements, you may prefer to use a different function than round() to make $newtime and integer again suitable for formatting with date()

Comment: The is wrong .. remove or correct it  ... `date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', microtime () );` is not a valid format http://codepad.viper-7.com/Hc4qfE

Comment: I didn't expect it would be used in that way. Have amended my answer to be clearer

Comment: That is still not a valid way to add 0.5 sec .... your code rounds it up to 1 secs

Comment: yes, but the questioner wanted to display the date/time. As I said in my answer, (s)he may wish to use a different function than round() to convert the new value into an integer, depending on their requirements. In the end, if you're adding a fraction of a second but want to display the result in seconds, then you're always going to lose some fidelity.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of a Unix timestamp (which is what `time()` returns) is only 1 second. So you can't add half of a second to it.